# Rendering controls to the right not working with style="float: right"

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to render the controls to the right of the screen correctly. I tried to apply style="float:right" on the outer div but it isn't rendering correctly. Also I have applied     after each control. Just for your information I am using bootstrap v4. Could somebody tell me where I am going wrong.

Here is the stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rb9d3n

Html

```
<style>

</style>


<div style="width: 100%; padding-bottom: 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid #A8A8A8">
    <input-file placeholder="Select or drop files here..."  [(ngModel)]="Files"></input-file>
    <br/>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="postFiles()" [disabled]="!Files || Files.length == 0"
        style="width: 10rem;" title="Wait">Upload&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-paperclip"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img
        *ngIf="Uploading" src="../images/ajax-loader2.gif" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;"
        title="Select Attachments" /></button><span style="color:red; padding-left: 20px" *ngIf="Error && Error.length > 0">{{Error}}</span>
</div>

<div>
        <label for="inputEmail" class="col-form-label modal-label" style="width: 100px;">Type</label>


        <kendo-dropdownlist style="width:250px"
            class="form-control  form-control-sm"
             [filterable]="false"
            textField="Name" [valuePrimitive]="false" valueField="Id" 
            [defaultItem]="defaultItem"
            >
        </kendo-dropdownlist> &nbsp;


           <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 250px">Show Archived</button>  &nbsp;&nbsp;
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 250px">Include Related</button>   &nbsp;&nbsp;
           <label for="inputEmail" class="col-form-label modal-label" style="width: 100px">Name Filter</label>
           <input kendoTextBox  style="width: 250px" />

</div>


<div class="card" style="margin-top: 10px">
    <div class="card-body" style="width:100%; text-align: left;">
        <div style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; ">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="panel panel-default col-md-12  ">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div id="grid-wrapper" [style.height.px]="GridHeight()" [style.width.%]="100"
                            style="float: left;">
                            <ag-grid-angular #agGrid class="ag-theme-balham" [gridOptions]="GridOptions"
                                style="width: 100%; height: 100%" [columnDefs]="ColumnDefs"
                                rowHeight="30"
                                headerHeight="30" rowSelection="single">
                            </ag-grid-angular>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Screenshot - This is what I am trying to achieve

[image]

Tried the Bootstrap grid system

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>

    <div class="col-md-2"><label style="width: 20%" for="inputEmail" class="modal-label">Type</label>


        <kendo-dropdownlist class="form-control  form-control-sm" style="width: 80%" [filterable]="false"
            textField="Name" [valuePrimitive]="false" valueField="Id" [defaultItem]="defaultItem">
        </kendo-dropdownlist>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Show Archived</button></div>
    <div class="col-md-1"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Include Related</button></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"> <label for="inputEmail" style="width: 30%" class="modal-label">Name
            Filter</label>
        <input kendoTextBox style="width: 70%" /> </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the stackblitz but it's not working..

Comment: Can you please check the updated link and let me know if you can access it

Comment: You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to provide a [mcve] here on Stack Overflow instead.

Comment: Since I have already created the minimal reproducible code on stackblitz do I need to create snippet.

Comment: I have tried the bootstrap grid system. Is that fine. When I try to shrink the screen though i can see them overlapping at one point

Comment: It's a good improvement but now the website has lacked its styles so the issue can't reproduced yet. Can you fix this so we could actually see the problem and then we could try to debug it?

Comment: Here is the updated link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uaf3hd